# How can I check whether $date1 is before $date2 in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

```
date1=$1
date2=$2
```

How can I check whether $date1 is before $date2?

Both dates are in DD/MM/YY format i.e. 01/01/15.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: reopened because the linked question doesn't address the import issue of the dd/mm/yy format.

Comment: Not really a duplicate since this is DD/MM/YY format, I think it can be done easier and better than the answer provided.

Comment: @Jack: If you want to provide an *unambiguous* example of your data format, 01/01/15 is not a great example, since 01 could be anything. Try January 23, 2042 or some such.

Comment: @rici Sorry I don't understand your comment. It says `DD/MM/YY`, what do you not understand?

Comment: @jack: I understood perfectly, but "i.e. 01/01/15" doesn't help clarify. If you'd said "23/01/15", it would be obvious that the `23` couldn't be a month (although it could be a year, since 15 could be a day. Hence the suggestion in my comment.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can compare two dates by using the `date` utility to convert them to seconds from epoch, and then comparing the two numbers.

### Linux

With GNU date, that would look like:

```
# Linux, assumes MM/DD/YY dates so it won't work in your case. See below.
if (( $(date +%s -d "$date1") < $(date +%s -d "$date2") )); then
  # $date1 is earlier
else
  # $date1 is not earlier (could be the same as date2)
fi
```

However, you need to make sure that the date input formats are understandable to the `date` program. Sadly, the format `dd/dd/dd` is ambiguous: it could be the US-style `MM/DD/YY` or it could be the traditional Canadian style `DD/MM/YY`. In practice, GNU date interprets dates with <kbd>/</kbd> delimiters as month-first (`MM/DD/YY`). Dates with <kbd>-</kbd> delimiters are interpreted as year-first (`YY-MM-DD`).

That being the case, if your dates are really `DD/MM/YY`, you'll need to rearrange the date formats in order to use the `date` utility, or just compare the three numbers yourself. (The disadvantage of the latter is that you will need to work through all possible corner cases, including the possibility that the `YY` refers to some other century.)

```
# Linux, assumes DD/MM/YY dates.
IFS=/ read d1 m1 y1 <<<"$date1"
IFS=/ read d2 m2 y2 <<<"$date2"
if (( $(date +%s -d "$m1/$d1/$y1") < $(date +%s -d "$m2/$d2/$y2" )); then
```

**Note:** If you knew for sure that $y1 and $y2 represent years in the same century and that both the month and the day are two digit numbers, you could do the comparison directly -- `if (($y1$m1$d1 < $y2$m2$d2)); then` -- but this is highly unrecommended since it is very fragile. A variety of fixes are possible, but using `date` is the easiest.

### BSD/Mac OS X

All this is easier with the BSD `date` utility, also used on OS X, since that utility allows you to specify an explicit `strptime` format, in your case `%d/%m/%y`:

```
# BSD/Mac, assumes DD/MM/YY dates. Adjust `-f` format as appropriate.
if (( $(date -f '%d/%m/%y' "$date1" +%s) < $(date -f '%d/%m/%y' "$date2" +%s) )); then
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
newDate1=$(awk -F '/' '{print $2"/"$1"/"$3}' <<< $date1)
newDate2=$(awk -F '/' '{print $2"/"$1"/"$3}' <<< $date2)
date1s=$(date --date=$newDate1 +%s)
date2s=$(date --date=$newDate2 +%s)

if [[ $date1s -gt $date2s ]];then
    ..date stuff
fi
```

this is assuming date1 and date2 are after 1970, and that your dates really are in the DD/MM/YY format reliably. I just tested this in BSD, and it doesn't work, so this answer would only be good for Gnu/Linux.

EDIT: fixed for DD/MM/YY convert to MM/DD/YY

Comment: Try it. It's MM/DD/YY. (`date --date=10/01/15` outputs `Thu Oct 1`)

Comment: typo, meant mm/dd/yy, thanks for the correction. But brain bloop, I missed it was supposed to be DD/MM oh well.

Answer (score 0):

First get the day, month and year:

```
day1=`echo $date1 | sed -e 's:/.*::'`
year1=`echo $date1 | sed -e 's:.*/::'`
month1=`echo $date1 | sed -e 's:[^/]*/::' | sed -e 's:/.*::'`
```

You can do the same for the other date. Then:

```
if [ $year1 -lt $year2 -o \( $year1 -eq $year2 -a $month1 -lt $month2 \) -o \( $year1 -eq $year2 -a $month1 -eq $month2 -a $day1 -lt $day2 \) ]; then
    echo "date1 lt date2"
fi
```